# How to prevent the user from accessing other parts of the page until the customized alert box is closed?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, reactstrap

I have built a customized alert box using the reactstrap package and importing the Alert from it.
But I am facing one issue that I am not being able to freeze the page or prevent the user from accessing the other parts of the page when the alert box is shown. So I need some help regarding this issue as I am new to reactjs and have not find anything helpful regarding this problem.

Problem Example :
We can take an example of the alert box that is shown when we put "windown.alert()" in which a browser's alert box is shown and we cannot access any part of the webpage until we confirm the alert box.

Comment: You could put fullscreen absolute not-clickable div between alert and site

Comment: you need an overlay with 100% width and position fixed and height 100% z-index 1. Every button behind it cant be clicked until ur box is closed. Show the overlay when your alert pops up close it wenn the user closes the alert box.

Comment: Thank you so much Michi , your comment has helped me as I have added the overlay div and now the problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical approach is to:

1. Set `overflow: hidden` on the `body` element
2. Place an absolutely positioned element the height and width of the viewport on the page to absorb clicks
3. Place your content on top of that

This won't stop people from using DOM tools to access the content, but it will prevent accidental clicks there.

```js
addEventListener('load', init);

function init() {
  document
    .querySelector('button')
    .addEventListener('click', close);

  function close(e) {
    document.querySelector(".modal-active").classList.toggle("modal-active");
  }
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.modal-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-background,
.modal-content {
  display: none;
}

.modal-active .modal-background {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.8);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modal-active .modal-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
  background: rgb(100, 200, 100);
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-active">

  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <button>Hello</button>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras interdum leo lacus, quis vestibulum nunc ultrices at. Quisque id tempus justo, id faucibus massa. Suspendisse laoreet gravida urna id interdum. Etiam in risus nisl. Proin ipsum massa, sagittis
    vel laoreet a, porttitor eu tellus. Nam vestibulum, mi nec vestibulum placerat, velit purus hendrerit augue, at sollicitudin tellus diam id ante. Donec ultricies erat sit amet nibh rhoncus malesuada.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras interdum leo lacus, quis vestibulum nunc ultrices at. Quisque id tempus justo, id faucibus massa. Suspendisse laoreet gravida urna id interdum. Etiam in risus nisl. Proin ipsum massa, sagittis
    vel laoreet a, porttitor eu tellus. Nam vestibulum, mi nec vestibulum placerat, velit purus hendrerit augue, at sollicitudin tellus diam id ante. Donec ultricies erat sit amet nibh rhoncus malesuada.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras interdum leo lacus, quis vestibulum nunc ultrices at. Quisque id tempus justo, id faucibus massa. Suspendisse laoreet gravida urna id interdum. Etiam in risus nisl. Proin ipsum massa, sagittis
    vel laoreet a, porttitor eu tellus. Nam vestibulum, mi nec vestibulum placerat, velit purus hendrerit augue, at sollicitudin tellus diam id ante. Donec ultricies erat sit amet nibh rhoncus malesuada.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras interdum leo lacus, quis vestibulum nunc ultrices at. Quisque id tempus justo, id faucibus massa. Suspendisse laoreet gravida urna id interdum. Etiam in risus nisl. Proin ipsum massa, sagittis
    vel laoreet a, porttitor eu tellus. Nam vestibulum, mi nec vestibulum placerat, velit purus hendrerit augue, at sollicitudin tellus diam id ante. Donec ultricies erat sit amet nibh rhoncus malesuada.</p>

</div>
```